# Join table in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have problem, i cannot join in table, why what wrong? can you help me?

[image: tabel 1]

[image: table 2]

```html
public function getIndex()
 { 
  $posts = DB::table("users")
  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
  ->select("users.id","users.created_at","companies.name as nama_companies","users.privilege_type","users.name","users.name","users.email","users.password")
  ->join("companies","companies.created_at","=","users.id_kategori","companies.photo") 
  ->paginate(5); 
  
  return view('users',['posts'=>$posts]);
 }
```

please help me, thanks

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you trying to do? Your code says "go from the users table, then join it with the companies table (on fields that make no sense, did you mean select?), then return posts".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

`$posts = User::join('companies', 'companies.name', '=', 'users.name')
        ->orderBy('user.id', 'desc')
        ->select(array("users.id","users.created_at","companies.name as nama_companies","users.privilege_type","users.name","users.name","users.email","users.password"))->paginate(5);`

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins

[image: Join Arguments]

replace square brackets with your condition and operators for instance.

```
->join("companies", "id_companies", "=" , "companies.id")
```

Your code will look like..

```
$posts = DB::table("users")
         ->select("users.id",
                  "users.created_at",
                  "companies.name as nama_companies",
                  "users.privilege_type",
                  "users.name",
                  "users.email",
                  "users.password")
           ->join("companies", [ ColumnName ], [Condition] , [ColumnName])  //replace square brackets.. 
           ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
           ->paginate(5);
```